# materialized view mechanism

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

i learn materialized view for reporting by database. the materialized view as shown on this site [https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-materialized-views/#:~:text=PosgreSQL%20extends%20the%20view%20concept%20to%20a%20next,then%20allow%20you%20to%20refresh%20this%20result%20periodically](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-materialized-views/#:%7E:text=PosgreSQL%20extends%20the%20view%20concept%20to%20a%20next,then%20allow%20you%20to%20refresh%20this%20result%20periodically). The data in materialized view is depends on the last time you deploy from the table, if the table is being updated, you have to refresh materialized view to have full data. I have search to many sites but, i need to know this materialized view mechanism.

If the data insert into main table and i use refresh materialized view for being updated, does the materialized view truncate or insert mechanism?

or if the data drop in main table and missing some, then i refresh materialized view, is dropping data like truncate or just dropping?

Thank you for your explanation

Comment: When you call `REFRESH` postgres will run the underlying query one more time and replace the existing data with the new one. The entire dataset is recreated from scratch each time (note that it may be time consuming).

Comment: yes, i was thinking of it. i dont know what this materialized view does.  when i have a huge dataset insert/ drop into a table, does data in materialized view truncate (that means drop and insert again) or just append to existing. this case actually need to be noticed for time consuming, and i still research and proofing

Comment: The standard refresh destroys the old data, executes query and inserts new data. It may be different with concurrent refresh. Since it requires primary key to be defined on the view, I think it may create a diff between current view and new view and apply the diff. That would mean a huge performance boost when there is a big query with little changes. Perhaps you can test that?